# How to prove with identities: (A - B) ∩ (C - D) = (A ∩ C) - (B ∪ D)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove with identities: 
(A - B) ∩ (C - D) = (A ∩ C) - (B ∪ D)

Comment: The general method used to prove set equality is that by proving both sets as subsets of each other . You can use that to prove this .

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have
$$\begin{align}
 (A\cap C) - (B\cup D)&=(A\cap C)\cap (B\cup D)^c\\
&=(A\cap C)\cap (B^c\cap D^c)\\
&=(A\cap B^c)\cap (C\cap D^c)\\
&=(A - B) \cap (C - D) 
\end{align}$$
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Let $B'$ stand for "not $B$" and so forth.

By the definition of $A-B$,
$$
A-B = A \cap B' \\
C-D = C \cap D'
$$
whence
$$
(A-B)\cap(C-D) = (A \cap B')\cap(C \cap D') \mbox{   [definition of X-Y]} \\
= A\cap(B'\cap C)\cap D' \mbox{   [associativity of intesecton]}\\
= A\cap(C\cap B')\cap D' \mbox{   [commutativity of intersection]}\\
= (A \cap C)\cap(B' \cap D') \mbox{   [associativity of intesecton]}\\
= (A \cap C) \cap [B\cup D]' \mbox{   [intersection of negation = negation of union]}\\
= (A \cap C) - (B\cup D) \mbox{   [definition of X-Y]} 
$$